# How to change a property class in sub class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to re-write some code of old project, and ideally I want to achieve below code style, but I got a lot of compile error saying dataModel don't have getLineColor method.

The abstract question is, can I change an inherited object A's class in sub view controller to a sub class A2, while the object A in parent view controller is class A1 that is the super class of A2, and how can I do it correctly? Thank in advance.

Update: I compile it, but I have met another run time error, I tried to overwrite the setter of dataModel in sub view controller. How to correctly write the setDataModel in sub class?

```
@implementation SubViewController
#pragma mark - setter of dataModel
- (void)setDataModel:(ChartModel *)dataModel { // it stucks at this func name
@end
```

error trace is

```
[SubChartViewController setDataModel:](self=0x00000000, _cmd=0x00000000, dataModel=0x00000031) + 12 at BDPAxisChartViewController.m:295, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf774ffc)
```

EDIT:

```
@interface ChartModel : NSObject
-(BOOL)chartModelhasData;
@end

@interface LineChartModel : chartModel
-(void)getLineColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* seriesNameArray;
@end

@interface ChartViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChartModel *dataModel;
-(void)layoutChartCanvas;
@end

@implementation ChartViewController
-(void)layoutChartCanvas {
    if ([self.dataModel chartModelhasData]) {
        self.view.hidden = NO;
    }
}
@end

@interface LineChartViewController : ChartViewController
// pay attension here, same name but a sub class of chartModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) LineChartModel *dataModel; 
-(void)drawLine;
@end

@implementation LineChartViewController
-(void)drawLine {
    UIColor *color = [self.dataModel getLineColor];
    [self drawLine];
    NSArray *tempArray = [self.dataModel.seriesNameArray copy];
}
@end
```

Comment: `Can I change an inherited object A's class in sub class to a sub class A2, while the object A in base class is class A1 that is the super class of A2, and how can I do it correctly?` DAFAQ? You completely lost me there...

Comment: check the code exmaple, also improved the readability

Comment: `better OOP` yet you can't even name your classes correctly... It should always camel case with Capital letter.

Comment: then please help me on the format and the quesiton, thanks.

Comment: @Wingzero I have no problem to do so. Do you get the error in the above statement `[self drawLine]` or somewhere else?

Comment: @Wingzero I added an answer because the clarification of the situation would be too long for a comment. Please comment, whether I understood it correctly.

Comment: the compiler is saying the dataModel don't have drawLine method.

Comment: Well, better OOP could mean a lot, but I would say create a factory that returns the right view controller for a given model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to say:

> Can I change the class C of a property already declared in a base class in a subclass to a subclass of C?

This is the set-up

```
@interface PropertyClass : NSObject
@end

@interface PropertySubclass : PropertyClass
- (void)method;                              // Additional method
@end

@interface HolderClass : NSObject
@property PropertyClass *property;           // Property is of base class
@end

@implementation HolderClass
@end

@interface HolderSubclass : HolderClass
@property PropertySubclass *property;        // Property is of subclass
@end
```

I have no problem to access the property subclass' method in the holder's subclass:

```
@implementation HolderSubclass
- (void)useIt
{
  [self.property method]; // No error or warning
}
@end
```

In addition to my comment below, I suspect that something like this happens:

```
// Create a subclass' object
HolderSubclass *object1 = [HolderSubclass new]; 
…

// Refer this object from a reference that is typed to HolderClass
// **This applies to all usages of self inside @implementation HolderClass**
HolderClass *object2 = object1; // Of course more complex

id value = [object2 method]; // Error
```

This error is correct. If this is the error, it is solvable. But first we have to clarify that.

---

BTW: This has nothing to do with better OOP. First of all this is a problem of class based programming languages, not of object orientated programming languages. Second I cannot see that this set-up will break a rule of class based or object orientated programming, esp. it fulfills Liskov's rule.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I would refrain from naming the property `property`, even if this is a hypothetic example.

Comment: I wouldn't, because `property` is no keyword, but `@property` is one. It is a compilable example.

Comment: I am useing dot notation to access it like, self.property.method, and got errors, my error like  Property 'seriesNameArray' not found on object of type 'ChartModel *'  and I declare @property NSArray *seriesNameArray in ChartModel

Comment: change to `[self.dataModel seriesNameArray]` also report error

Comment: It works with dot-notation as well for me (as expected). However the problem is that if you have a reference typed to the base class (`HolderClass `) you will get errors, even the concrete instance object is of `HolderSubclass`. For this situation there is a solution. Can you add an example of an erroneous line in your Q? Include the place and the definition of the reference variable, too.

Comment: It's not a keyword in Xcode, but it is on SO (As you can see from the syntax highlighting).

Comment: I do not adopt my code for SO, esp. if it is completely without meaning for Q and A.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I have updated my quesiton demo code, could you check? I typed demo code by hand in web editor, and pretty close the the real project code. The project code is very messy, so you cannot undserstand without context

Comment: @Wingzero  In the update of your Q I cannot see a marker for the erroneous line. Please make a simple minimal project that generates the error as I did. (You can use my source code for this. The whole interfaces and implementations can go in one single file, if you want to, to make it easier.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, I solved the compilor error, but I met another run time error, please check the updated quesiton. the problem is, how to re-write setDataModel in sub class?

Comment: @Wingzero Great that you solved that. My assumption was correct? For the runtime error open a new Q, please. Otherwise we have a discussion on SO instead of Q-A-paris. Please add code there that is minimal. Include the code of the method that throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks let me debug it first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573504/best-practice-for-how-to-inherit-property-from-parent-class-and-override-setter   It turned out I need a better code style for overrding setter and getter

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is declare a `LineChartModel` variable and not property and `@synthesize` dataModel to that ivar:

```
@interface LineChartViewController: ChartViewController {
     LineChartModel *_lineChartModel;
}
-(void)drawLine;
@end

@implementation LineChartViewController
synthesize dataModel = _lineChartModel;
....
```

So from the outside it looks like you have a `ChartModel`, but inside the class you have `LineChartModel`. You will have to apply changes to `_lineCharModel` directly inside your class.

**HOWEVER this is NOT my definition of better OOP!!!** There's clearly a fault with the design if you need to cast your variables in subclass.

---

Another option I discovered after pasting this code into the editor is just use `self.variable` (which by the way, you should've already been doing).

```
@interface ChartModel : NSObject
- (BOOL)chartModelhasData;
@end

@interface LineChartModel : ChartModel
- (UIColor *)getLineColor;
@end

@interface ChartViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChartModel *dataModel;
- (void)layoutChartCanvas;
@end

@implementation ChartViewController
- (void)layoutChartCanvas {
    if ([self.dataModel chartModelhasData]) {
        self.view.hidden = NO;
    }
}
@end

@interface LineChartViewController : ChartViewController
// pay attension here, same name but a sub class of chartModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) LineChartModel *dataModel;
- (void)drawLine;
@end

@implementation LineChartViewController
- (void)drawLine {
    UIColor *color = [self.dataModel getLineColor];
    [self drawLine];
}
@end
```

Comment: First of all thank you, I have delete the 'better' word... The reason is the old project I was assigned is has something like that code example, and the old project is not a good OOP. every view controller has a dataModel and many same code and messes up with the views, so I want to use inheritance to remove some duplicated code. I know the old style is bad, could you give some better solutions for this?

Comment: I hae updated the quesiton, add a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* seriesNameArray;` in LineChartModel, will your solution works fine with propery variable in LineChartModel?

Comment: I type the demo code in web editor, so forgive me if any typo, the demo code is not copy pasted from file. I have updated self.dataModel in quesiton