# best practice for how to inherit property from parent class and override setter and getter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to re-struct my project code with an inheritance style, what is the best practice for how to inherit property from parent class and override setter and getter?

I give the demo code, in the demo, ChartModel is a base class in a ChartViewController, and LineChartModel is a sub class of ChartModel in LineChartViewController.

I want to override the setter and getter of `LineChartModel *dataModel` in sub view controller. Please include any @synthesize and protected instance variable, or if it is automatically generated by compiler, please mark. Thank in advance.

```
// ChartModel.h
@interface ChartModel : NSObject
-(BOOL)hasData;
@end

// LineChartModel.h
@interface LineChartModel : chartModel
-(void)getLineColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* dataArray;
@end

// ChartViewController.h
@interface ChartViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChartModel *dataModel;
-(void)updateUI;
@end

// ChartViewController.m
@implementation ChartViewController
-(void)updateUI {
    if ([self.dataModel hasData]) {
        [self.view setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        self.view.hidden = YES;
    }
// setter and getter here
@end

// LineChartViewController.h
@interface LineChartViewController : ChartViewController

// pay attension here, same name but a sub class of chartModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) LineChartModel *dataModel; 

@end

// LineChartViewController.m
@implementation LineChartViewController

//override dataModel setter here
//override dataModel getter here

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the only thing you need in the implementation of `LineChartViewController` is:

```
@dynamic dataModel;
```

That tells the compiler that the getter and setter will be supplied in some way it can't immediately see. In actuality, they will be supplied by the superclass.

However, that allows for a problem. A `LineChartViewController` is-a `ChartViewController`. That means that an instance of `LineChartViewController` can be passed to a method or function which is declared to take a `ChartViewController` and that method/function is entitled to do anything to it that is allowed by the interface of `ChartViewController`. That includes assigning an instance of `ChartModel` (not `LineChartModel`) to its `dataModel` property. Presumably, `LineChartViewController` will break if its `dataModel` property is not a `LineChartModel`.

In technical terms, your design violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

It's not a fix for the design issue, but you can catch the problem at run time if it happens, by implementing an override of the setter like this:

```
- (void) setDataModel:(LineChartModel*)dataModel
{
    if (dataModel && ![dataModel isKindOfClass:[LineChartModel class]])
    {
        NSString* reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is not a valid dataModel for LineChartViewController; it must be a kind of LineChartModel", dataModel];
        [[NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException reason:reason userInfo:nil] raise];
    }
    [super setDataModel:dataModel];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The purpose is that some UI methods in ChartViewController will need self.dataModel, and I want to inherit these methods, so I don't have duplicated code in sub class, is this also works fine? I have updated my question, check `updateUI` func

Comment: could you also specify, how to declare the instance variable _dataModel in sub class? is it can be LineChartModel *_dataModel in class extension?

Comment: Yes, that will work fine. However, it provides more flexibility and avoids this problem with the `dataModel` property to just have a method for the purpose. For example `- (BOOL) shouldBeHidden` or (less purpose-specific) `- (BOOL) hasData`. Then, the subclass can implement that however it wants. It might have a `dataModel` property or it might not, and the superclass doesn't care about its type.

Comment: Your design violates the contravariance of method arguments in the subtype. It would be permissible to make `-setDataModel:` take a wider variety of types, but you're trying to make it take a narrower variety. As I described, something could assign a `ChartModel` instance to the `dataModel` property of a `LineChartViewController` instance (because it only knows it through a pointer-to-`ChartViewController`) but that will break things.

Comment: There is no instance variable in `LineChartViewController` for the `dataModel` property. It uses the instance variable from `ChartViewController`. Indeed, it uses the accessors, too. It has only overridden the types of the accessors. (The type of the instance variable doesn't matter because, at run time, it's just a pointer to an object type, and they're all interchangeable.)

Comment: Another way of looking at the LSP violation is that you're attempting to impose additional preconditions on the setter. You require that the passed-in object be a kind of `LineChartModel`, which is not a precondition of the superclass's setter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74984/discussion-between-wingzero-and-ken-thomases).

Comment: If you want to discuss further, use comments. I don't care that SO discourages it. I don't do chat.